# How to get the result using the " incrBy" function in redis with PHP programing?

Tags: php, nginx, redis

```
$redis->setOption(Redis::OPT_SERIALIZER,Redis::SERIALIZER_PHP)
$redis->incrBy('inum4', 100, 86400);
$redis->get('inum4');
```

when using get function , 502 error happen in nginx!

```
$redis->setOption(Redis::OPT_SERIALIZER,Redis::SERIALIZER_NONE)
$redis->incrBy('inum4', 100, 86400);
$redis->get('inum4');
```

if close the serializer , it works well!

Comment: Did you just try `$myVar = $redis->incrBy('inum4', 100, 86400);`? If it doesn't work, what library do you use?

Comment: $myVar = $redis->incrBy('inum4', 100, 86400);  this works well! what doesn't work is the get function!

Comment: Sorry, no idea. What Redis driver are you using?